# Is it possible to assign a model to ionSlide or get selected slide (not index) from ionSlideBox?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm working in a way to present a bi-dimensional list inside an Ionic Application (along with AngularJs). I currently have an API which outputs a json object much like the following:

```
[
    [
      { id: 1, loaded: false, thumbnail: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/sauro/128.jpg", description: "1" },
      { id: 2, loaded: false, thumbnail: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jsa/128.jpg", description: "2" },
      { id: 3, loaded: false, thumbnail: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/k/128.jpg", description: "3" }
    ],
    [
      { id: 4, loaded: false, thumbnail: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/jadlimcaco/128.jpg", description: "4" },
      { id: 5, loaded: false, thumbnail: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rem/128.jpg", description: "5" },
      { id: 6, loaded: false, thumbnail: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/csswizardry/128.jpg", description: "6" }
    ]
  ]
```

Every item on the parent array is a new array of slides (ie, items to be displayed horizontally, one at a time).

Using Ionic's list template and a couple of it's components (ionSlideBox and ionSlide), I was able to come up with the following markup:

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false" class="list" ng-repeat="row in list">
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="column in row" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
    <img ng-src="{{column.thumbnail}}">
    <h2>{{column.description}}</h2>
    <p>{{column.loaded}}</p>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

My problem is: I need to execute code whenever a slide is activated for the first time and set the "loaded" property to true.

However, ionSlideBox's option **on-slide-changed** only gives me the ability to take the index of the activated slide. In my case, this doesn't really help me because even if I know the slide's index, I still need to figure out from which array it belongs.

The dimensions here are both dynamic and can be any number at any time.

You can see a sample running here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdhRl2BHVkJRCtK7sQgf?p=preview

If **on-slide-changed** would support more parameters, I could pass the outer array index along with the selected slide index (inner array index) but I can't figure out a way to make it happen.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `on-slide-changed` is an expression, which gets called when the slide changes. Because of this, you can use any function call with any parameters currently in scope. Slide box injects one more variable: `index` with index of the slide the slide box is sliding to.

Thus you only need the outer index, which is also already in scope, in this case from the `ng-repeat` directive, named `$index`.

Let's use it in your app:

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false" class="list" ng-repeat="row in list" 
        on-slide-changed="onSlideChanged($index, index)">
```

with handler in scope:

```
$scope.onSlideChanged = function(index1, index2) {
    var item = $scope.lista[index1][index2];
    if (!item.loaded) {
        item.loaded = true;
        console.log("ITEM LOADED:", item);
    }
};
```

or even move array accessing to view:

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false" class="list" ng-repeat="row in list" 
        on-slide-changed="onSlideChanged(list[$index][index])">
```

with handler in scope:

```
$scope.onSlideChanged = function(item) {
    if (!item.loaded) {
        item.loaded = true;
        console.log("ITEM LOADED:", item);
    }
};
```

New [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PTe5rdXWL4aJM55kZ4kw?p=preview)

Comment: That works perfectly! I thought the delegate function executed by "on-slide-changed" was always going to have only $index. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)
For future reference: Currently, there is an error in documentation of `on-slide-changed` - the injected variable is named `index`, not `$index`, that is the variable of `ng-repeat` directive. My answer has it right.